# Plotting continuous and discrete series in ggplot with facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that plots over time with four different variables. I would like to combine them in one plot using facet_grid, where each variable gets its own sub-plot. The following code resembles my data and the way I'm presenting it:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

subm <- melt(economics, id='date', c('psavert','uempmed','unemploy'))
mcsm <- melt(data.frame(date=economics$date, q=quarters(economics$date)), id='date')
mcsm$value <- factor(mcsm$value)


ggplot(subm, aes(date, value, col=variable, group=1)) + geom_line() + 
       facet_grid(variable~., scale='free_y') + 
       geom_step(data=mcsm, aes(date, value)) + 
       scale_y_discrete(breaks=levels(mcsm$value))
```

If I leave out scale_y_discrete, R complains that I'm trying to combine discrete value with continuous scale. If I include scale_y_discreate my continuous series miss their scale.

Is there any neat way of solving this issue ie. getting all scales correct ? I also see that the legend is alphabetically sorted, can I change that so the legend is ordered in the same order as the sub-plots ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Problem with your data is that that for data frame `subm` `value` is numeric (continuous) but for the `mcsm` `value` is factor (discrete). You can't use the same scale for numeric and continuous values and you get y values only for the last facet (discrete). Also it is not possible to use two `scale_y...()` functions in one plot.

My approach would be to make `mcsm` `value` as numeric (saved as `value2`) and then use them - it will plot quarters as 1,2,3 and 4. To solve the problem with legend, use `scale_color_discrete()` and provide `breaks=` in order you need.

```
mcsm$value2<-as.numeric(mcsm$value)
ggplot(subm, aes(date, value, col=variable, group=1)) + geom_line()+
 facet_grid(variable~., scale='free_y') + geom_step(data=mcsm, aes(date, value2)) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=c('psavert','uempmed','unemploy','q'))
```

[image]

### UPDATE - solution using grobs

Another approach is to use grobs and library `gridExtra` to plot your data as separate plots.

First, save plot with all legends and data (code as above) as object `p`. Then with functions `ggplot_build()` and `ggplot_gtable()` save plot as grob object `gp`. Extract from gp only part that plots legend (saved as object `gp.leg`) - in this case is list element number 17.

```
library(gridExtra)
p<-ggplot(subm, aes(date, value, col=variable, group=1)) + geom_line()+
  facet_grid(variable~., scale='free_y') + geom_step(data=mcsm, aes(date, value2)) +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=c('psavert','uempmed','unemploy','q'))
gp<-ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gp.leg<-gp$grobs[[17]]
```

Make two new plot `p1` and `p2` - first plots data of `subm` and second only data of `mcsm`. Use `scale_color_manual()` to set colors the same as used for plot `p`. For the first plot remove x axis title, texts and ticks and with `plot.margin=` set lower margin to negative number. For the second plot change upper margin to negative number. `faced_grid()` should be used for both plots to get faceted look.

```
p1 <- ggplot(subm, aes(date, value, col=variable, group=1)) + geom_line()+
   facet_grid(variable~., scale='free_y')+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.5,-0.25,0.5), "lines"),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#F8766D","#00BFC4","#C77CFF"),guide="none")

p2 <- ggplot(data=mcsm, aes(date, value,group=1,col=variable)) + geom_step() +
  facet_grid(variable~., scale='free_y')+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(-0.25,0.5,0.5,0.5), "lines"))+ylab("")+
  scale_color_manual(values="#7CAE00",guide="none")
```

Save both plots `p1` and `p2` as grob objects and then set for both plots the same widths.

```
gp1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p1))
gp2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p2))
maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gp1$widths[2:3],gp2$widths[2:3])
gp1$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
gp2$widths[2:3] <- as.list(maxWidth)
```

With functions `grid.arrange()` and `arrangeGrob()` arrange both plots and legend in one plot.

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(arrangeGrob(gp1,gp2,heights=c(3/4,1/4),ncol=1),
       gp.leg,widths=c(7/8,1/8),ncol=2))
```

[image]

Comment: I was optimistically hoping that I would be able to combine the two types as I expect in the future to use the fourth graph with data that is not possible to represent numerically. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: @sgunnars Added solution which give you representation of both data types.

Comment: Nice to see it is possible. In the data I have, there are two things that I have not in place. First I get complaint about the gp.leg. Second the continuous and discrete functions differ slightly on the x-axis. Wasn't the `maxWidth = grid::unit.pmax(gp1$widths[2:3],gp2$widths[2:3])` to take care of that ? If so it is not working for me.

Comment: maxWidth line makes both plots the same width but it doesn't change the axis values - you should try to make scales the same in both plots. For the gp.leg - look on object gp and see in which line "guide-box" is located (it won't be number 17 in every case)

Comment: I was misunderstanding the first bit and therefor not using it. Thanks for really good answers.