# ggplot2 error : Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset called "merged", which contains 3 numeric columns "pauseMedian" and "numTotalPauses" and "diff". I also have a splineHull dataset, which also contains numeric columns "pauseMedian" and "numTotalPauses", plus a 6-level factor "microstyle"

I have the following code, which works perfectly. It plots a scatter plop and then overlay it with splineHull polygons colored according to "microstyle".

**script 1:**

```
ggplot(data=merged,aes(x = pauseMedian, y = numTotalPauses)) 
       + geom_point()  
       + geom_polygon(data = splineHull, 
                      mapping=aes(x=pauseMedian, 
                                  y=numTotalPauses, 
                                  group=microstyle, 
                                  color = microstyle),
                       alpha=0)
```

Then, I also want to change the color of the points in the scatter plot by adding just one attribute color = diff.

**script 2:**

```
ggplot(data=merged,aes(x = pauseMedian, y = numTotalPauses, color = diff)) 
       + geom_point()  
       + geom_polygon(data = splineHull, 
                      mapping=aes(x=pauseMedian, 
                                  y=numTotalPauses, 
                                  group=microstyle, 
                                  color = microstyle),
                       alpha=0)
```

I see the following error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I don't know why I see this error. If I still want colored scatter plot but no polygons, I run the following code it works again.

**script 3:**

```
ggplot(data=merged,aes(x = pauseMedian, y = numTotalPauses, color = diff)) 
       + geom_point()
```

So, what happened with **script 2**, where is the error from, and how can I make it work?

Comment: That does seem weird - it's hard to pinpoint the error without seeing example data. Also, have you tried moving `color=diff` to `geom_point(aes(color=diff))`?

Comment: @SeñorO Hi, yes I tried that. It gave the same error. In script 2, there are two color attributes, one in the ggplot aes, the other in the geom_polygon aes. The former is assigned a numeric value "diff", the latter is assigned a factor value "microstyle". I guess, maybe ggplot cannot handle a numeric color and a factor color at the same time?

Comment: Actually that may be correct now that I think about it - because it needs to make a legend for the color. Try using `fill = microstyle` for polygon

Comment: You don't need to post your whole dataset. Just post a small sample that will allow us to reproduce the problem using your data. For example, post of the output of `dput(merged[sample(1:nrow(merged),20),])`. That will give 20 randomly selected rows of your data (do the same for splineHull).

Comment: Using some fake data that (I hope) is similar to your data, I was able to get the same error message. However, when I reverse the order of `geom_polygon` and `geom_point`, I get `Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale`. There seems to be a conflict between the color scales of the two geoms, one being discrete, the other being continuous, but I'm not sure why that's happening. I would have thought having two separate geoms would result in two separate colour scales.

Comment: @eipi10 I think your fake data is similar to mine. I just tried to switch the order of geom_polygon and geom_point, I also got that error. Before I also thought color scales for different geoms do not interfere with each other. Do you have a solution, or an alternative way of achieving the same effect for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Evidently, you can't have different color aesthetics for two different geoms. As a workaround, use a fill aesthetic for the points instead. This means you have to use a point marker style that has a filled interior (see `?pch` and scroll down for the available point styles). Here's a way to do that:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=merged,aes(x = pauseMedian, y = numTotalPauses, fill = diff),
             pch=21, size=5, colour=NA) +
  geom_polygon(data = splineHull, 
               mapping=aes(x=pauseMedian, 
                           y=numTotalPauses, 
                           colour = microstyle),
               alpha=0)
```

Adding `colour=NA` (outside of `aes()`), gets rid of the default black border around the point markers. If you want a colored border around the points, just change `colour=NA` to whatever colour you prefer.

Also see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/MEyMz1TMlvU) from the `ggplot2` Google group, discussing a similar problem and some workarounds.

Comment: This is great (+1), but as per Juan's answer below `colour = "NA"` must have quotation marks, otherwise the points will not be plotted.

Answer (score 4):

Now that we know the two color vars are of different types, there's the issue. You can try using a different scale for one (e.g. fill instead of color)

```
set.seed(123)
my_df1 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=runif(100), c=rep(1:10, 10))
my_df2 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100), b=runif(100), c=factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5], 20)))
 
# this won't work. can't assign discrete and continuous to same scale
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=my_df1, aes(x=a, y=b, color=c)) +
  geom_polygon(data=my_df2, aes(x=a, y=b, color=c), alpha=0.5)
```

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

```
# but use fill for polygons, and that works:
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=my_df1, aes(x=a, y=b, color=c)) +
  geom_polygon(data=my_df2, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=c), alpha=0.5)
```

[image: plot output]

If you have to use the same scale (color), and can't convert the variables to the same type, see this for more info: [Plotting continuous and discrete series in ggplot with facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999304/plotting-continuous-and-discrete-series-in-ggplot-with-facet)

Comment: Hi, I've got a very large dataset, so it's difficult to post the data here. alpha should be more than 0, but it is not the problem, and I only need to contour not filled polygon, because the plot simply does not show up due to the error. I tried your solution but I got the same error. For the color specified in geom_point, it is a numeric variable "diff", the one specified in geom_polygon is a discrete "factor". I am just guessing ggplot does not work if color attributes are assigned with different types.

Comment: Oh, well that's the key piece of missing info. See new solution

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes it works this way. Actually I still prefer color, because I want to have just the contour (empty polygons). Anyway, this solution works for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add something to the preferred eipi10 answer above (thank you for that!!).
The colour="NA" option in order to get rid of the border around the circle shape (pch=21) has to be between "". If you use colour=NA (without the quotation marks) the whole shape disappears and is not plotted. 
I would have just commented on the answer but I still don't have reputation for that :)

Comment: So glad to see this! I spent a long time wondering why I couldn't get it to work. Although `colour = "NA"` will give a white border, so if there are overlapping points/ geoms the border will still be visible.