# How to put the actual data points on the contour plot with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code below produces a contour plot using ggplot.

```
xgrid <-  seq(min(mtcars$wt), max(mtcars$wt), 0.3)
ygrid <-  seq(min(mtcars$hp), max(mtcars$hp), 0.3)

data.fit <-  expand.grid(wt = xgrid, hp = ygrid)

data.loess <- loess(qsec ~ wt * hp, data = mtcars)
mtrx3d <-  predict(data.loess, newdata = data.fit)

mtrx3d[1:4, 1:4]

require(reshape)
mtrx.melt <- melt(mtrx3d, id.vars = c("wt", "hp"), measure.vars = "qsec")
names(mtrx.melt) <- c("wt", "hp", "qsec")

require(stringr)
mtrx.melt$wt <- as.numeric(str_sub(mtrx.melt$wt, str_locate(mtrx.melt$wt, "=")[1,1] + 1))
mtrx.melt$hp <- as.numeric(str_sub(mtrx.melt$hp, str_locate(mtrx.melt$hp, "=")[1,1] + 1))

ggplot(mtrx.melt, aes(x = wt, y = hp, z = qsec)) + stat_contour()
```

[image]

I wonder how to show all acutal data points with the contour lines. I have tried

```
ggplot(mtrx.melt, aes(x = wt, y = hp, z = qsec)) + 
  stat_contour() + geom_point(mtrx.melt, aes(x = wt, y = hp, z = qsec))
```

but this returned an error message said

`Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`

This is similar to this question [how-can-i-overlay-points-and-lines-onto-a-contour-plot-with-ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468576/how-can-i-overlay-points-and-lines-onto-a-contour-plot-with-ggplot2) but is based on different situation. In that question, op wants to annotate a contour plot with particular points that he wants to highlight (where these points are stored in a different data set). My case is to highlight all original data points in `mtrx.melt`. I tried the method in that question but failed to work.

[image: This is the plot that I expected]

The plot above is not based on the dataset, it is just what I expect to have, I want to have a contour plot with its original data points.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I overlay points and lines onto a contour plot with ggplot2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468576/how-can-i-overlay-points-and-lines-onto-a-contour-plot-with-ggplot2)

Comment: @aelwan I have updated my question and I don't think this is a duplicate since my case is different although it looks like similar to that one at the first glance.

Comment: You got this error because `data` must be referenced. `data=mtrx.melt`. Also `geom_point()` does not have `z` aesthetics

Comment: @ErdemAkkas Yeah, it seems like geom_point() cannot achieve my goal. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues which prevent to produce the desired result. Some of which are already mentioned in comments.

However, the OP wants to *show the actual data points* but is trying to plot the regular grid `mtrx.melt` which is used to interpolate the data, instead.

The follwing code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtrx.melt, aes(x = wt, y = hp, z = qsec))+ 
  geom_point(aes(colour = qsec), mtcars) +
  stat_contour(aes(colour = ..level..))
```

creates

[image]

which is probably what the OP is looking for.

Please, note

- the contour levels are color coded now.
- the actual data points from the `mtcars` data set are shown.
- the order of parameters in calls to `geom_point()` and the like is different from `ggplot`. The geoms and stats expect the aesthetic `mapping` as first parameter and `data` as second.
- `geom_point()` is called before `stat_contour()` to ensure that the legend title is `qsec` instead of `level`. Beware when replacing `stat_contour()` by `geom_tile()`. Then the tiles have to be plotted as first layer and the points on top.

**EDIT** In response to [this comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268692/how-to-put-the-actual-data-points-on-the-contour-plot-with-ggplot/43271775#comment73672018_43271775), the code could have been written as well as

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = wt, y = hp, z = qsec)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = qsec), mtcars) +
  geom_contour(aes(colour = ..level..), mtrx.melt)
```

This makes it more explicit that two layers, i.e., `geom_point()` and `geom_contour()`, are being used to display data of two different data sources. The aesthetics which are shared between both layers are placed in the initial `ggplot()` call (which is possible here because `mtcars` and `mtrx.melt` use the same column names). The `colour` aesthetic is different, so each layer uses its own definition.

In the call to `ggplot()`, it's now required to specify the parameter name `mapping = aes(...)` because `ggplot()` expects `data` as first parameter if unnamed.

`geom_contour()` is used here as the code  appears more consistent and it seems to be preferred over `stat_contour()` following the examples on the `ggplot2` [documentation site](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is absolutely what I expected. Btw, I have a question about the usage of `aes()`. Why sometimes it includes `x`,`y`,`z` but sometimes it includes `colour` and it seems like `x` and `colour` cannot be switched.

Comment: @BrattSwan I've added a code variant and some explanation to my post which should answer your question. What do you mean by _`x` and `colour` cannot be switched_? If it's about the position of parameters in the call to `aes()`, all parameters need to be named except `x` and `y` but then they must be the first two parameters. see `?aes`.