# how to solve Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale on r

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

Hi this is my code the error shows when i run the code for the graphic. Im trying to do a graphic of bars and lines. But i dont know what is wrong. When i run it appears this error Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale and i dont know what it means that warning

```
# Se accesan los nombres####



colnames(datos)

# se modifican los nombres de columnas####
colnames(datos) <- c("Fecha", "Por")
colnames(datos)

# Lo primero es ordenar los trimestres
datos$Fecha <- factor(datos$Fecha,
                      levels = c("enero 2018", "febrero 2018", "marzo 2018", "abril 2018", "mayo 2018", "junio 2018", "julio 2018", "agosto 2018", "setiembre 2018", "octubre 2018", "noviembre 2018", "diciembre 2018", "enero 2019", "febrero 2019", "marzo 2019", "abril 2019", "mayo 2019", "junio 2019", "julio 2019", "agosto 2019", "setiembre 2019", "octubre 2019", "noviembre 2019", "diciembre 2019"),
                      labels = c("Enero-2018", "Febrero-2018", "Marzo-2018", "Abril-2018", "Mayo-2018", "Junio-2018", "Julio-2018", "Agosto-2018", "Setiembre-2018", "Octubre-2018", "Noviembre-2018", "Diciembre-2018", "Enero-2019", "Febrero-2019", "Marzo-2019", "Abril-2019", "Mayo-2019", "Junio-2019", "Julio-2019", "Agosto-2019", "Setiembre-2019", "Octubre-2019", "Noviembre-2019", "Diciembre-2019"))



#grafico de lineas y barras
ggplot(datos, aes(Fecha, Por)) +
  #se agregan las barras
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") +
  #Se agregan los numeros que representan las barras
  geom_text(aes(label = Por), vjust = -0.3, size = 2.5, nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0.3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  # se define el alto del eje Y
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(-1,1.15,0.25), limits = c(-1,1.15)) +
  # se da color a las barras
  geom_line(group=1, size=0.5) +
  # se agregan marcadores y se define el tamaño
  geom_point(size=1) +
  ggtitle("Tendencia de la inflacion por variacion mensual", subtitle = "Periodo: Enero 2018 - Septiembre 2019") +
  # se eliminan los titulos de los ejes
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())+
#Se rotan las etiquetas del eje x
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10))

# se modifican los nombres de columnas####
colnames(datos) <- c("Fecha", "VarAcu")
colnames(datos)

#grafico de lineas y barras
ggplot(datos, aes(Fecha, VarAcu)) +
  #se agregan las barras
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "steelblue") +
  #Se agregan los numeros que representan las barras
  geom_text(aes(label = VarAcu), vjust = -0.3, size = 2.5, nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0.3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  # se define el alto del eje Y
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(-1,1.15,0.25), limits = c(-1,1.15)) +
  # se da color a las barras
  geom_line(group=1, size=0.5) +
  # se agregan marcadores y se define el tamaño
  geom_point(size=1) +
  ggtitle("Tendencia de la inflacion por variacion Interanual", subtitle = "Periodo: Enero 2018 - Septiembre 2019") +
  # se eliminan los titulos de los ejes
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())+
  #Se rotan las etiquetas del eje x
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=10))
```

Comment: The error is in the second graphic code

Comment: You should try to give a reproducible example i.e. give a sample data which is causing the error.

Comment: The problem might be that `VarAcu` is a discrete variable (I presume, as you are using it as text labels), but you are using `scale_y_continuous`.  Try commenting out the `scale_y...` line and see if that solves it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 error : Discrete value supplied to continuous scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937000/ggplot2-error-discrete-value-supplied-to-continuous-scale)