# Parse plot lines by more than one variable ggplot

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2, facet-wrap, line-plot

I am desiring to plot two levels of data (high, low) for two days (day o,  day 1) for both male and female subjects.  I have been success in faceting by day and by level.  However I am unsuccessful of combining and identifying the genders. I would like to show the male/female together on day 0 and day 1.  Below is specific code I have been trying to create.
Thanks in advance

```
data <- function(ids,time_vec) {
obs.data <-  
data.frame(expand.grid(ids,time_vec),DOSE=0,Conc=rnorm(13,10,2),Day=0) 
names(obs.data) <- c("ID","TIME","DOSE","Conc","Day")
obs.data<-obs.data[order(obs.data$ID),]
return(obs.data)
}

test<-data(ids=1:4, time_vec= seq(0,120,10))
test$Gender<-ifelse(test$ID==1|test$ID ==3,"Male","Female")
test$Day<-ifelse(test$ID==1|test$ID==2,"Day 1","Day 2")
test$DoseLevel<-ifelse(test$ID==1|test$ID==2,"Low","High")

gf1<-ggplot(test,aes(x=TIME, y=(Conc), group=interaction(DoseLevel,Day, 
   Gender)))+
  geom_line(size=1.25)+
  facet_grid(DoseLevel~.,as.table=FALSE)
gf1

gf2<-gf1+  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(Day), fill=factor(Day), 
colour=factor(Day)),size=4,show_guide=TRUE)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 21))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("black","white"))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("black","black"))
gf2
```

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you:
[Plotting continuous and discrete series in ggplot with facet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999304/plotting-continuous-and-discrete-series-in-ggplot-with-facet)
Just take care the using `melt` function.

Comment: I am not sure whether this link helps. I see no example of combining plots one variable while faceting on another. Am I missing something?